# National Proficiency Test Scores: Sample or Population?

Tags: distributions, sample, skewness, population, kurtosis

If I want to compute the skewness and kurtosis of my data sets comprising of scores, which came from a national proficiency test/national external quality assessment scheme in a span of a few years, should I treat the data as samples or as population? The proficiency test involved participation of laboratories throughout the country.

Comment: Well, whether your data are the entire population or just a sample from the population depends on whether your data are the entire population or just a sample from the population. Were your laboratories sampled, or do you have data from all labs? (You will likely need to account for nonrespondents, which would make your data a non-random sample. Survey statistics may be helpful.)

Comment: That depends on the question you're asking. "I want to compute X" isn't a question. What is it that you want to find out?

Comment: It was supposed to test all laboratories in my country but there were a lot of non-respondents so my data involves only those who enrolled in the proficiency test and submitted their reports to the challenges.

Comment: I want to find out if the proficiency tests over the years have an effect (increase in the number of passers/good performance of laboratories, increase in scores) on the performance of laboratories throughout the country.